# Export from GIS to static html clickable hypermap?

Tags: raster, export, html

What plugins or tools are available to conveniently export a GIS view to a html clickable hypermap?

Since 2005 or so we use a commerial plugin for ArcGIS,

We have a working example of the output [here](http://www.icdp-online.org/upload/iframedata/world.html).
At this time, this is good enough, but it requires a few manual postprocessing steps, which should be reduced. Besides, the annual license for the plugin is considered a nuisance from a corporate accounting standpoint.

Now we are wondering if there are better alternatives.

Here are our requirements

- Export a GIS view map to a bitmap, Correctly export it without distortions and with valid html, preferably with style information extra (in css), no proprietary attributes inside the html...
- Export point features to clickable <area> elements. Make the points clickable, *but also make the labels clickable.*
- Export as a single bitmap, do not convert to tiles
- Export without a sidebar (only export the map, not the layer selection frame and other stuff such as trademark infos, "created with" footers in the bitmaps, etc.)
- Aesthetic alignment of labels next to points
- Label alignment configurable, set preferences and priorities image-wide (try to put label to the right of a point. If there is a collision with another label, then put label at the top of a point, etc)
- *Possibility to re-align + re-format labels individually* after semiautomatic/algorithmic alignment steps have completed
- it's ok when based on free software. However, if we switched to this software, it should be able to import ArcGIS 9 project files.
- easy to use, preferably gui-based

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it won't import your ArcGIS project files, but QGIS has the [HTML Image Plugin](http://blog.qgis.org/node/105) that may do what you want. Perhaps if you set up a QGIS project once, and just refreshed the data behind it, it would work for you? It may not meet *all* of your criteria, but I'm not sure anything will.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used [this ArcScript](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14574) before, so I'm not sure which of your criteria it does or does not meet, but it sounds like a good starting place. And, of course, being a script you should be able to customize it to your heart's content.

Edit: [Here](http://clear.uconn.edu/training/maps/simple/download.htm)'s another potential candidate.

Comment: For those who come here searching for similar answers... the latter candidate points to http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=13796, which is a VBScript from 2005. The first link in this answer points to a VBScript for ArcGIS 9, last updated in 2007.

Answer (score 0):

Additional: the first link given by @nmpeterson has the following note at the bottom of its description:

> I am no longer using or updating this script. I have implemented a
>   very effective, and more reliable solution which is available here:
>
> http://cosmotron.org/2007/01/generating-html-image-maps.html

The newer solution linked to is no longer there, but can currently be accessed [at this URL via the Wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20081025072718/http://cosmotron.org/2007/01/generating-html-image-maps.html).

It works very differently. Instead of starting with an ArcGIS project, it starts from an image (with a unique color for each clickable region) and a CSV table that maps from colors to href and title (rollover text). So you would still need a way to get the specialized image files, and the CSV files.

The script does not place labels, as in the OP's requirement.